# Fetch multiple rows in join

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, join

I have a bit of trouble with the following sql...

First step is:

Fetch one row from a table an join multiple rows from another table... the result array should look like this:

```
array(
  field_1, 
  field_2, 
  field_3, 
  joined_array(
    field_a_array(
      field_a_a, 
      field_a_b, 
      field_a_c
    ), 
    field_b_array(
      field_b_a, 
      field_b_b, 
      field_b_c
    )
  ) 
)
```

My query looks something like this:

```
SELECT table_1.*, table_2.*
FROM table_1
JOIN table_2 ON table_2.field_1 = table_1.field_1
WHERE table_1.field_1 = xyz
```

But it returns only one row from the "table_2"...

So, what am I doing wrong ?

Edit because of comment #1:

The above query is not the actual query, only a rewrite of me.

I use codeigniter as framework, so the query is build by a codeigniter class... the code for the query is the following:

(it seems that the position of where, join, etc isn't important for the codeigniters db class)

```
$this->db->select('events.*, genres_x_events.*');

$this->db->from('events');
$this->db->where('events.slug', $slug);
$this->db->where('events.deleted', 0);

$this->db->join('genres_x_events', 'genres_x_events.event_slug = events.slug');

$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Consider copy/pasting in the actual query.  I'm guessing you just typed in the query in your question with some errors.  So the syntax related answers probably won't be much help.

Comment: would like to, but i use codeigniter as framework, so theres no real actual querry, only a few lines codiginter db-class-functions...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `.` after `table_2`. And your `JOIN` should be *before* the `WHERE` condition:

```
SELECT table_1.*, table_2.*
FROM table_1
JOIN table_2 ON table_2.field_1 = table_1.field_1
WHERE table_1.field_1 = xyz
```

Comment: thanks, i corrected that in the topic - but sadly thats not the problem of the querry ;(

Comment: @jacksbox I suggest you write a new question is the problem is different from the original one. Editing your question is a bad idea, because now both answers don't make any sense. Your original question didn't mention codeigniter and wasn't tag as such.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a dot:

Where it says, "table_2*" I added a dot for you:

```
SELECT table_1.*, table_2.*
FROM table_1
JOIN table_2 ON table_2.field_1 = table_1.field_1
WHERE table_1.field_1 = xyz
```

Comment: thanks, i corrected that in the topic - but sadly thats not the problem of the querry ;(